# Friction caused by acceleration on a rocket sled

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, torque, rotational-kinematics

I'm trying to quantify some intuition I have about friction and rocket sled.
[image: body diagram]
Suppose a rectangular sled with length $l$, weight $W$ on a surface with friction coefficient $\mu$. A rocket attached height $h$ from the ground on the middle of the sled exerts force $H$ causing the sled to accelerate, call the right pad Pad1 and left pad Pad2. Find the difference of friction between Pad1 and Pad2.
(assume the weight of the sled is big enough to not go flying, flipping or something unusual, if will only accelerate to the right)

Of course, the sum of friction on Pad1 and Pad2 would be (weight of the sled) x (coefficient of friction). And if H was not there, the difference would be zero because the weight of the sled will be balanced evenly on the two pads ie) same normal force. But since there is that $H$ force, I think I have to account for that, so I tried using my intuition.

My intuition is telling me Pad1 should have greater friction, I think $H$ should push down on Pad1 and it will push up on Pad2, with the same magnitude, causing the balance of friction to "tip over" to Pad1, but the sum of the pad would stay the same as $W\mu$. I can't quite quantify how much of this "unbalance" occurs, though. any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct.

If the sled is not to tip over or otherwise lose contact with the ground, the sum of the vertical forces on the sled must equal zero and the sum of the moments about any point on the sled must be zero.

Neglecting the weight of the rocket, summing the vertical forces give us

$$-W+R_{1}+R_{2}=0$$

$$R_{2}=W-R_{1}$$

Where $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ are the upward vertical reactions at Pads 1 and 2 respectively.

Again, neglecting the weight of the rocket, the sum of the moments about contact surface of Pad 2 with the surface is (clockwise moments being positive):

$$Hh-R_{1}L+\frac{WL}{2}=0$$

$$R_{1}=\frac{W}{2}+\frac{Hh}{L}$$

Plugging this into the vertical forces equations to determine $R_2$

$$R_{2}=\frac{W}{2}-\frac{Hh}{L}$$

So the reaction force on Pad 1 is greater than that on Pad 2. Since the reaction forces are the forces normal to the friction surface, the friction force on Pad 1 is greater than Pad 2.

So your intuition is correct. The friction force is greater on Pad 1 then Pad 2.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there any reason the axis should be on the sled? I can find couple of examples on the outside that doesn’t work (one example would be to raise the axis on Pad2 by h) but I can’t exactly state why it should be on the sled. And the devil’s advocate in me is saying the sum of moment should be zero no matter the axis, cause the thing is not turning!

Comment: What do you mean by the “axis”?

Comment: “The sum of the moment about any point on the sled..” the axis is taken in the z direction on the point that you would specify, I believe that’s how you take torque in 2D. In other words, why must the sum of the moments be zero when a point is taken INSIDE the sled, what’s the logical derivation to not take a point, say, outside the sled?

Comment: For rotational equilibrium the sum of the moments anywhere (inside or outside the sled) is zero. You pick a point that eliminates variables.

Comment: What about a point that’s above the Pad2 (the left one) by h? It seems no torque is provided by Pad1’s reaction force, Pad2’s torque stays the same (cause the lever arm stays the same) and torque on the middle of the sled decreases because there is no torque H anymore. So it seems there is non zero torque!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "above Pad 2 by h". Do you mean on top of the sled directly above Pad 2? On top of the sled near the rocket? You need to be precise. In any case, you can't pick a point to take moments if you don't have sufficient information to determine the moments. No information is given on the height between the ground and the top surface of the sled, or the thickness of the sled.

Comment: No information is given on the dimensions of the pads (and for that reason I had to take moments about the end points of contact with the pads and the ground as if the pads were concentrated at a point). The only dimensions you are given is $L$ and $h$. So your moments have to involve one of those dimensions times a force perpendicular to those dimensions ($H$, $R_1$, $R_2$, and/ or $W$).

Comment: If you look closely at my answers for $R_1$ and $R_2$ you’ll see they make sense. As  $H$ or $h$ approaches zero (i.e., the moment due to $H$ approaches zero), $R_{1}=R_{2}=W/2$. It is the moment, or torque, due to $H$ that causes the sled to increase the reaction force at Pad 1 while decreasing it at Pad 2. I’m afraid that’s about all the time I have to spend on this. Sorry.

Comment: Wait! come back! I meant on top of the sled directly above Pad2! I don't know why I have to take the moment relative to points on the ground to be zero. I swear to god, try it, try to calculate moment from the point directly above Pad2 with height h, the torque is not zero!

Comment: How can you take the moment about the top of the sled above Pad 2 due to $H$. To get the moment of $H$ about that point you would need to know the vertical distance between the top of the sled to the point of application of the force $H$. You don't have that information. All you have is the distance from the ground to $H$, i.e., $h$.

Comment: No, I think you only need the distance from the ground to H, taking that point above Pad 2 by height h as the origin, the vector $\vec{r}$ that points to the point of application of force H is $(l/2,0)$, $\vec{H} = (H,0)$ so the cross product is zero, the torque by H with respect to a point above Pad 2 with height h is zero! Please prove me wrong, this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't make sense of what  you are saying without seeing a free body diagram of the sled showing the exact location where you want to take moments. You need to edit your question to do that and provide the equations for the moments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111723/discussion-between-user208685-and-bob-d).

Comment: There is no point in continuing in chat unless you first provide a free body diagram showing the point about which you want to take moments

Comment: Yes, I think that's better handled in the chat, I think I now have another question regarding your answer and why the method works, (even though I intuitively understands your answer, it still doesn't survive the rigor of my personal devil) and I think I want to edit my question and maybe your answer after I know why I can arrive at the answer that way. (find the sum of moments, set it to zero, etc)

Comment: I also provided the diagram in the chat and the equations about the sum of moments in there. Please, I request your patience and expertise to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You are concerned about rotational stability. You have the vertical force equation: $N_f$ + $N_r$ - mg = 0  with two unknown N's at the front and rear. Combine that with a torque equation taken about the front support: Hh + $N_r$L – mg(L/2) = 0.  You need $N_r$ to be greater than zero.